# How to show that if vectors are solution of one equation then they are a solution of another equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem that asks:

Show that if the vectors $s =  \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
        s_1\\
        s_2\\
        \vdots\\
        s_n\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$ and $p =  \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
        p_1\\
        p_2\\
        \vdots\\
        p_n\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$ are the solutions of the equation 
$$ a_1x_1 + a_2x_2+...+ a_nx_n = d$$

then the vector $h = s - p =  \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
        s_1-p_1\\
        s_1-p_2\\
        \vdots\\
        s_n-p_n\\
      \end{array}
    \right]$ is a solution of the equation $$ a_1x_1 + a_2x_2+...+ a_nx_n = 0$$

Could someone walk me through this or give me steps on what to do here? I have other problems that are similar to this one so general steps are better than just solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what it means for those vectors s and p to be solutions to that equation? Can you write it out in full?

Have you tried just plugging the vector h in directly? i.e.

$a_1(s_1 - p_1) + a_2(s_2-p_2) + \dots + a_n(s_n-p_n),$

and expanding out the brackets, and seeing what you get?

Comment: So to do this problem I just write what it means for the vectors to be solutions to the equation and plug in vector h and show that it equals 0?

Comment: Sure, that'll do it.

Comment: Okay sweet, thanks.